# C++: Why does this give me an exception thrown error when I want to enter 'q' to quit?

Tags: c++

Sorry I don't want to get accused of cheating again lol

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Think about what `temp = temp->link;
        delete temp;` does.  Is `temp` useable in the next iteration?

Comment: Learn to use a debugger to step through the code to figure out these sorts of problem yourself. It's never too early to learn to use what will be the most useful tool in your toolbox in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Queue` destructor is not looping through the nodes correctly.

On the 1st loop iteration, you make `temp` skip over the 1st node and point to the 2nd node, then you `delete` the 2nd node and don't update `temp`, so `temp` is now pointing at an invalid node on the 2nd loop iteration.

Try this instead:

```
Queue::~Queue()
{
    //create new pointer and point it to front of list
    QueueNodePtr temp = front;

    //while list is not empty
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        //point to next node and delete the current node
        QueueNodePtr next = temp->link;
        delete temp;
        temp = next;
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
Queue::~Queue()
{
    //create new pointer and point it to front of list
    QueueNodePtr temp = front;

    //while list is not empty
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        //point to next node and delete the current node
        QueueNodePtr curr = temp;
        temp = temp->link;
        delete curr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your destructor code is deleting the wrong node.  Change to:

```
while (temp != NULL)
{
    QueueNodePtr next = temp->link;
    delete temp;
    temp = next;
}
```